# Zend or Symfony which one has a smaller memory footprint

Tags: php, zend-framework, symfony1, content-management-system

While i'm not questioning which one is better than which,while i recognized their strong areas.this question is simply to help me decide on which one to use for a simple project with requires a very small memory foot print.

So that's about it. Who has a better insight when it comes to that?
Thanks for reading this

Comment: Why not choose a framework or library meant to lightweight (CodeIgniter, maybe)?

Comment: If you search for `very lightweight php framework`, there are apparently many that specialize in this area.

Comment: i like your suggestion Jared ;) but i have to learn it ^_^, that adds another level, am reading right now cakephp documentation

Comment: This question might be useful, as well, although possibly a little dated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58424/a-lightweight-application-framework-for-php (Note, they also mention Doctrine in the accepted answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would choose neither for a simple / smaller project. Choose Codeigniter, it's easier to setup and it's one of the lightest resources intesive wise.

Comment: learning ci is a breeze. watch the video tutorials for a blog creation on the official site. it's nothing to it

Comment: seems you are more and more convincing me.thanks for your help.i think i would buy that.in fact i've also heard that it has easy integration with doctrine (which i use already quite well)

Answer (score 4):

If your project really is simple, your best option is a microframework, like [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/). It is a PHP microframework for PHP 5.3. It is built on the shoulders of Symfony2 and Pimple and also inspired by sinatra.

A microframework provides the guts for building simple single-file apps. Silex aims to be:

- Concise: Silex exposes an intuitive and concise API that is fun to use.
- Extensible: Silex has an extension system based around the Pimple micro service-container that makes it even easier to tie in third party libraries.
- Testable: Silex uses Symfony2's HttpKernel which abstracts request and response. This makes it very easy to test apps and the framework itself. It also respects the HTTP specification and encourages its proper use.

In a nutshell, you define controllers and map them to routes, all in one step:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/silex.phar'; 

$app = new Silex\Application(); 

$app->get('/hello/{name}', function($name) use($app) { 
    return 'Hello '.$app->escape($name); 
}); 

$app->run();
```

All that is needed to get access to the Framework is to include silex.phar. This phar (PHP Archive) file will take care of the rest.

*(most content taken from Silex's homepage)*